# Get attribute from many divs to toggle class

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to check a bunch of divs on an inbox page and I am returning an array from an AJAX call to know which divs to change the font-style of. To achieve this, I have to first check their data-value attribute and then add/remove a class(bold vs. normal fro read/unread messages). The problem is that when I refer to the messageDiv object, it toggles all the messages on the page. Looping through the messages makes the most sense to me, but I do not know how to store a div an array to achieve this.

```
data['messages']=[3,5,8,9]

var messageDiv=$('.widget .inbox-row');

if (data['status']=='A'){//read
    if ($.inArray(messageDiv.data('value'),data['messages']) && messageDiv.hasClass('unread-msg')) {
        messageDiv.removeClass('unread-msg').addClass('read-msg');
    }
}

if (data['status']=='N'){//unread
    if ($.inArray(messageDiv.data('value'),data['messages']) && messageDiv.hasClass('read-msg')) {
        messageDiv.removeClass('read-msg').addClass('unread-msg');
    }
}
```

This is what a message looks like, iterated many times on the page:

```
<div class="<?php echo $message_read_status; ?> inbox-row" data-value="<?php echo $messageid; ?>" >
            <?php echo $body; ?>
    </div>
```

Sincere thanks for any help. Sorry if this is a pretty specific question. I tried to make it as non-specific as possible.

Comment: what is the condition `data['status']=='A'` suppose to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `e` is a set of elements, so when you say `messageDiv.data('value')`, it will return teh data-value of the first element in the set.

You need to iterate over each item in the array and run the conditions against each one

```
var messageDiv = $('.widget .inbox-row');

messageDiv.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (data['status'] == 'A') { //read
        if ($.inArray($this.data('value'), data['messages']) > -1 && $this.hasClass('unread-msg')) {
            $this.removeClass('unread-msg').addClass('read-msg');
        }
    } else if (data['status'] == 'N') { //unread
        if ($.inArray($this.data('value'), data['messages']) > -1 && $this.hasClass('read-msg')) {
            $this.removeClass('read-msg').addClass('unread-msg');
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch. still not working, but I'll keep playing around with it and let you know if I get it/have to make any changes.

Comment: it's still changing the class of every div.

Comment: @ambe5960 can you tell me what should happen in this sample - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5g4vszjd/

Comment: OK thanks, changed it. It should now only change 3 and 8 to green.

Comment: but it still changes them all.

Comment: @ambe5960 http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5g4vszjd/3/ - the inArray condition was wrong - it returns the index of the item if found, -1 if not so we need to check `> -1` to see if an item is found

Comment: Thanks so much. You're the man! Should have read up more on inArray before using it.